# Create categories to group by in Acces SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, categorization

I am building a database to keep record of patients i have seen.
I enter different kinds of data, including age.
Here's what i am trying to do:
count the amount of patients, and categorize them by `age <1`, `<6`,`6-70 and >70`

Here is the code I am using, however this brings back all the ages uncategorized:

```
select Registratie.leeftijd as [Leeftijd], count(*) as [Aantal]
From Registratie
Where Registratie.opleidingsjaar = 1
Group by Registratie.leeftijd
```

What is the easiest way of doing this?

Comment: And what column has the age?

Comment: the first, and the second is the count

Answer (score 0):

Being limited in my Dutch (presumably), I'll do this in English.

You can use `switch()`:

```
select switch(age < 1, "< 1",
              age < 6, "1-5",
              age < 70, "6-69",
              1=1, "70+"
             ) as agegrp,
       count(*)
From Registratie as r
Where r.opleidingsjaar=1
Group by switch(age < 1, "< 1",
                age < 6, "1-5",
                age < 70, "6-69",
                1=1, "70+"
               )
order by min(age);
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. However, i ge an error message (i'll try to translate from dutch):
you have used invalid arguments in the expression switch

Comment: You need to replace _age_ with _leeftijd_ - and probably remove the _order by_ clause.

Comment: Yes, it works now!
Thank you very much for your help

Comment: It doesn't show Age <1 = 0, for example, because there are no entries in the age group <1.
Is it possible to tweak the output a bit more so it can also show 0?